# rsync to report file size using `--out-format`

Tags: backup, rsync

I would like `rsync` to report the file size at the source location for all files being reported when I use `--itemize-changes` or `--out-format`. For example, I know I can use the following format, `"%i %f"`, to provide the type of change and the file name; however, I cannot find the correct escape code for file size. I tried `%b` but seem that related to bytes transferred and reports `0` for files that are not being changed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: See answer on Superuser here: https://superuser.com/questions/1397262/rsync-to-report-file-size-using-out-format/1397286#1397286